# Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration error

Tags: android, eclipse, maven

This error has come up recently in my eclipse android maven project, and I don't know why.
Can you please have a look at my POM and screenShot, and tell me where I am going wrong please.  Thanks [image: error message]

here is my pom

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.blueMonkeyTech.joggerMotivator</groupId>
<artifactId>joggerMotivator</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>apk</packaging>
<name>joggerMotivator</name>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
        <artifactId>android</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>



<build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>attach-sources</id>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>


</build>
```

Comment: Possibly related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352208/how-to-solve-plugin-execution-not-covered-by-lifecycle-configuration-for-spring

Comment: @Raghuram
it didn't help :(  
I have been stuck on this for ages :(
Has anyone else had this problem? Does anyone know how to fix it? Getting desperate here

Comment: Please also see (and upvote) this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7028881/how-to-disable-m2e-build-in-eclipse-indigo

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Open your POM and click on the "Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration" error. This will give you the option to Discover new m2e connectors.

Select this and you should be automatically prompted to download and install the Android Connector.

Installing this should resolve your problems. You should probably uninstall the old 0.2.4 m2eclipse-android-integration as well in favour of the new 0.3.0 m2e-android version.

Please see the new site for more information:

http://rgladwell.github.com/m2e-android/

Comment: One thing u should not forget is upgrade the maven-android-plugin to a 3.x.x release currently I use 3.0.0-alpha-2

Comment: I couldn't see a plugin element for the maven-android-plugin @dewijones92 posted, so didn't think to mention it.

Comment: Well that is correct, just I spend some time around not updating the maven plugin and could not get it to work.

Comment: I followed these instructions and got :
Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:3.1.1:proguard (execution: default-proguard, phase: process-classes)

any idea how I can get rid of this error?

I'm using android-maven-plugin 3.1.1 and 0.4 version of the connector.

Comment: Hi Patricio, that is a known issue. There is a fix in the trunk but it hasn't been released yet. you can install the master/snapshot version using the following Eclipse update site: http://rgladwell.github.com/m2e-android/updates/master/

Comment: I just followed http://rgladwell.github.com/m2e-android/ and stuck at the last step, because there(Eclipse Indigo (3.7.2) for Java Developers on Linux) is no "Discover new m2e connectors" option when you click on "Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration" error, instead I've to go to Window -> Preferences -> Maven -> Discovery -> Open Catalog and install "Android Connector" from there.

Comment: @wik can you please verify if the m2e marketplace is installed?

Comment: @RicardoGladwell yes, it is installed :)

Comment: I'm using the eclipse version 3.7.2, and i've installed the market place using the following "http://download.eclipse.org/mpc/indigo/" but still i could not get the "Android Connector" installed on my eclipse, i tried the Maven -> Discovery but it did not list android connector.. please help

Comment: @Sam what errors are you getting? its not clear from your comment.

Comment: @Sam Have you found the solution, I am also facing same issue.