# Import project written in maven into Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, maven

I'm new to Android and I'm implementing Twitter integration. For this purpose, I use twitter4j (http://twitter4j.org).
The libs downloaded from the above page have some examples. I can test these examples (written by maven tool) using Readme file step by step in Terminal. However, I want to test in Eclipse, so I try to convert these examples into Eclipse by command: mvn eclipse:eclipse. However, the target folder is empty.

How can I create Eclipse projects from these examples?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7114563/plugin-execution-not-covered-by-lifecycle-configuration-error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use eclipse plugin for maven

[Eclipse plugins for Maven](http://maven.apache.org/eclipse-plugin.html)

and also check this out

[here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/) and this answer will help you much: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2061645/1932105

Comment: Thanks, I can import Maven project now, but I cannot "Run as an android application"

Comment: Welcome, check here: http://maven-android-plugin-m2site.googlecode.com/svn/run-mojo.html

Comment: @AhmedEkri The link is dead.

Comment: Sorry, it been 3 months