# Eclipse android Maven : Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration (execution: ndk- build, phase: compile)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, maven, android-ndk

I have seen both of this SO question :

[Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7114563/plugin-execution-not-covered-by-lifecycle-configuration-error)

[com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2: Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13554694/com-jayway-maven-plugins-android-generation2-plugin-execution-not-covered-by-li)

And i tried to install the connector like those questions suggested. It get rid some errors, but i still got on error left :

```
Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: 
 com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:3.2.0:ndk-build (execution: ndk-
 build, phase: compile)
```

Im new in Maven and im out of idea to fix this issue.

This is my whole `pom.xml`, and i commented where the error is coming from :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>info.kghost.android</groupId>
    <artifactId>openvpn</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.4</version>
    <packaging>apk</packaging>
    <name>OpenVpn</name>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>sign</id>
            <activation>
                <file>
                    <exists>signkey.keystore</exists>
                </file>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-jarsigner-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.2</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>signing</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>sign</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <inherited>true</inherited>
                                <configuration>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>target/*.apk</include>
                                    </includes>
                                    <keystore>${basedir}/signkey.keystore</keystore>
                                    <alias>CERT</alias>
                                    <arguments>
                                        <argument>-digestalg</argument>
                                        <argument>SHA1</argument>
                                        <argument>-sigalg</argument>
                                        <argument>MD5withRSA</argument>
                                    </arguments>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                        <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.2.0</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <sign>
                                <debug>false</debug>
                            </sign>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>android</groupId>
            <artifactId>android</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2_r4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xpp3</groupId>
            <artifactId>xpp3</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.4c</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.khronos</groupId>
            <artifactId>opengl-api</artifactId>
            <version>gl1.1-android-2.1_r1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <url>https://github.com/kghost/ics-openvpn</url>
    <inceptionYear>2011</inceptionYear>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <scm.branch>master</scm.branch>
        <maven.version>3.0.3</maven.version>
    </properties>
    <scm>
        <url>https://github.com/kghost/ics-openvpn/tree/${scm.branch}</url>
        <connection>scm:git:git://github.com/kghost/ics-openvpn.git</connection>
        <developerConnection>scm:git:git@github.com:kghost/ics-openvpn.git</developerConnection>
    </scm>
    <issueManagement>
        <system>Github Issue Tracking</system>
        <url>https://github.com/kghost/ics-openvpn/issues</url>
    </issueManagement>
    <licenses>
        <license>
            <name>GPL</name>
            <url>LICENSE</url>
        </license>
    </licenses>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <!-- ERROR HERE -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>ndk-build</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>ndk-build</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <target>all</target>
                            <attachNativeArtifacts>false</attachNativeArtifacts>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>zipalign</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>zipalign</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <sdk>
                        <platform>16</platform>
                    </sdk>
                    <emulator>
                        <avd>22</avd>
                    </emulator>
                    <zipalign>
                        <verbose>true</verbose>
                    </zipalign>
                    <deleteConflictingFiles>true</deleteConflictingFiles>
                    <undeployBeforeDeploy>true</undeployBeforeDeploy>
                </configuration>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <filesets>
                        <fileset>
                            <directory>libs</directory>
                        </fileset>
                        <fileset>
                            <directory>obj</directory>
                        </fileset>
                    </filesets>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.3</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-scm-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <scmVersionType>branch</scmVersionType>
                    <scmVersion>${scm.branch}</scmVersion>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <autoVersionSubmodules>true</autoVersionSubmodules>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Build-Source-Version>1.6</Build-Source-Version>
                            <Build-Target-Version>1.6</Build-Target-Version>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0-beta-1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>enforce-maven</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>enforce</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <rules>
                                <requireMavenVersion>
                                    <version>[${maven.version},)</version>
                                    <message>Check for Maven version &gt;=${maven.version} failed.
                                        Update your Maven install.</message>
                                </requireMavenVersion>
                            </rules>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Please help me out, Thanks for your help.

**ANSWER**

Thanks to the answerer, i managed to edit his code, and this is my WORKING pom.xml :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>info.kghost.android</groupId>
    <artifactId>openvpn</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.4</version>
    <packaging>apk</packaging>
    <name>OpenVpn</name>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>sign</id>
            <activation>
                <file>
                    <exists>signkey.keystore</exists>
                </file>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-jarsigner-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.2</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>signing</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>sign</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <inherited>true</inherited>
                                <configuration>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>target/*.apk</include>
                                    </includes>
                                    <keystore>${basedir}/signkey.keystore</keystore>
                                    <alias>CERT</alias>
                                    <arguments>
                                        <argument>-digestalg</argument>
                                        <argument>SHA1</argument>
                                        <argument>-sigalg</argument>
                                        <argument>MD5withRSA</argument>
                                    </arguments>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                        <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.2.0</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <sign>
                                <debug>false</debug>
                            </sign>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>android</groupId>
            <artifactId>android</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2_r4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xpp3</groupId>
            <artifactId>xpp3</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.4c</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.khronos</groupId>
            <artifactId>opengl-api</artifactId>
            <version>gl1.1-android-2.1_r1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <url>https://github.com/kghost/ics-openvpn</url>
    <inceptionYear>2011</inceptionYear>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <scm.branch>master</scm.branch>
        <maven.version>3.0.3</maven.version>
    </properties>
    <scm>
        <url>https://github.com/kghost/ics-openvpn/tree/${scm.branch}</url>
        <connection>scm:git:git://github.com/kghost/ics-openvpn.git</connection>
        <developerConnection>scm:git:git@github.com:kghost/ics-openvpn.git</developerConnection>
    </scm>
    <issueManagement>
        <system>Github Issue Tracking</system>
        <url>https://github.com/kghost/ics-openvpn/issues</url>
    </issueManagement>
    <licenses>
        <license>
            <name>GPL</name>
            <url>LICENSE</url>
        </license>
    </licenses>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>[3.0.0-alpha-13,)</versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>ndk-build</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <execute />
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <!-- <execution>
                        <id>ndk-build</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>ndk-build</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <target>all</target>
                            <attachNativeArtifacts>false</attachNativeArtifacts>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution> -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>zipalign</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>zipalign</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <sdk>
                        <platform>16</platform>
                    </sdk>
                    <emulator>
                        <avd>22</avd>
                    </emulator>
                    <zipalign>
                        <verbose>true</verbose>
                    </zipalign>
                    <deleteConflictingFiles>true</deleteConflictingFiles>
                    <undeployBeforeDeploy>true</undeployBeforeDeploy>
                </configuration>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <filesets>
                        <fileset>
                            <directory>libs</directory>
                        </fileset>
                        <fileset>
                            <directory>obj</directory>
                        </fileset>
                    </filesets>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.3</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-scm-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <scmVersionType>branch</scmVersionType>
                    <scmVersion>${scm.branch}</scmVersion>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <autoVersionSubmodules>true</autoVersionSubmodules>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Build-Source-Version>1.6</Build-Source-Version>
                            <Build-Target-Version>1.6</Build-Target-Version>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0-beta-1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>enforce-maven</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>enforce</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <rules>
                                <requireMavenVersion>
                                    <version>[${maven.version},)</version>
                                    <message>Check for Maven version &gt;=${maven.version} failed.
                                        Update your Maven install.</message>
                                </requireMavenVersion>
                            </rules>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the android-maven-plugin samples code, you can try to add the following to your code (inside the pluginManagement tags):

```
<plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
          <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
```

And also include the following:

```
  <plugin>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
      <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
      <configuration>
        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
          <pluginExecutions>
            <pluginExecution>
              <pluginExecutionFilter>
                <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <versionRange>[3.2.0,)</versionRange>
                <goals>
                  <goal>manifest-update</goal>
                </goals>
              </pluginExecutionFilter>
              <action>
                <execute/>
              </action>
            </pluginExecution>
          </pluginExecutions>
        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Edited:
And the following snippet too:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
  <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.8.2</version>
  <configuration>
    <sdk>
      <platform>16</platform>
    </sdk>
    <emulator>
      <avd>23</avd>
      <wait>10000</wait>
      <!--<options>-no-skin</options> -->
    </emulator>
    <zipalign>
      <verbose>true</verbose>
    </zipalign>
    <undeployBeforeDeploy>true</undeployBeforeDeploy>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Thanks very much! I just need to move my ndk-build to the <pluginExecutions>, and commenting the old ndk-build <execution>

Comment: Why we need to do that change..? Explained here http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/documentation/m2e-execution-not-covered.html

Answer (score 2):

Please, consider adding the tag **< pluginManagement >** (and enclosing tag) in your pom.xml:

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
    ....
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, i forgot to said that i already tried this but its still not working