# M2e - plugin execution not covered by lifecycle

Tags: android, eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

OS: ubuntu 11.10

Eclipse: Java EE IDE for Web Developers. Version: Indigo Service Release 2 Build id: 20120216-1857
Java: jdk1.7.0_03
SDK adb :Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.29

Trying to build javaocr in eclipse by using m2e android (2.8.4).
it results in project being built with errors in pom.xml:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:maven-android-plugin:2.8.4:generate-sources (execution: default-generate-sources, phase: generate-sources)    pom.xml /javaocr-sampler    line 20 Maven Project Build Lifecycle Mapping Problem
Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:maven-android-plugin:2.8.4:unpack (execution: default-unpack, phase: process-classes) pom.xml /javaocr-sampler    line 20 Maven Project Build Lifecycle Mapping Problem
Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (execution: default-resources, phase: process-resources) pom.xml /javaocr-sampler    line 11 Maven Project Build Lifecycle Mapping Problem
Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5:testResources (execution: default-testResources, phase: process-test-resources)    pom.xml /javaocr-sampler    line 11 Maven Project Build Lifecycle Mapping Problem
```

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.javaocr.demos</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaocr-demos-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.102-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>net.sourceforge.javaocr.demos</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaocr-sampler</artifactId>
    <packaging>apk</packaging>
    <name>Android sampler</name>
    <description>
        Demo appliocation to gather samples for further training
        of matchers
    </description>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-android-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <sdk>
                        <platform>7</platform>
                    </sdk>
                    <emulator>
                        <avd>16</avd>
                    </emulator>
                    <deleteConflictingFiles>true</deleteConflictingFiles>
                    <undeployBeforeDeploy>true</undeployBeforeDeploy>
                </configuration>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.javaocr</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaocr-core</artifactId>
            <version>${pom.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.javaocr.demos</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaocr-android-camera-utils</artifactId>
            <version>${pom.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>android</artifactId>
            <version>2.1_r1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

I am completely new to maven, but have looked around for solutions for this, but i come up empty.
It is a project developed in IDEA (AFAIK) and it should work perfectly there, i just cant get IDEA to run neither :'-/
It javaocr [svn link](https://sourceforge.net/projects/javaocr/).

Comment: I no longer use the operating system which was involved on this configuration. So I'm afraid I cannot accept any answers since I cannot check if they solve the problem. My appologize.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem. This is how I solved it.
In the pom.xml file, change

```
<artifactId>maven-android-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.8.3</version>
```

for

```
<artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.4.1</version>
```

That solves it at least for me :)

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, you're using an old version of the android-maven plugin. You should upgrade to the latest, 3.1.1:

http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/

Secondly, please see section 3 of the instructions for installing the m2e-android plugin for m2e correctly:

http://rgladwell.github.com/m2e-android/

You can install m2e-android by opening your POM and clicking on the "Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration" error. This will give you the option to Discover new m2e connectors.

Select this and you should be automatically prompted to download and install the Android Connector.

Comment: same problem, Eclipse Indigo on Windows. When I click the error, I don't get any option to discover new connectors.

Comment: @parkerfath can you check if you have the m2e marketplace plugin installed, please?

Comment: @AndersMetnik did you run Maven -> Update Project Configuration... ?

Comment: @AndersMetnik also please note that the Android Maven Plugin artifact ID has changed maven-android-plugin -> android-maven-plugin.

Comment: @AndersMetnik also what version of m2e-android is installed?

Comment: @Ricardo - First of all, thank you for your persistancy in helping. Second, afraid it does nothing at all :-/

Comment: The newest m2e-android afaik(302 or something like that), how to check? :-)

Comment: @AndersMetnik go to Help -> About Eclipse and click the Installation Details button. If you click on the Plug-ins tab you'll see a list of the installed plugins with their versions. Did updating the artifactId not work?

Comment: I can't remember exactly how I worked aroud, but I think it involved downgrading my ADT (I think to v16) and possibly my Android SDK. With the lower-versioned ADT, I saw the clickable error message. But I don't remember the exact steps, so I unfortunately can't pass along a good answer.

Comment: Android Configurator for M2E 0.4.1 me.gladwell.eclipse.m2e.android.feature.feature.group Gladwell.me
  m2e - Maven Integration for Eclipse 1.0.200.20111228-1245 org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group Eclipse.org - m2e
  m2e - slf4j over logback logging (Optional) 1.0.200.20111228-1245 org.eclipse.m2e.logback.feature.feature.group Eclipse.org - m2e
  m2e connector for mavenarchiver pom properties 0.14.0.201109270543 org.sonatype.m2e.mavenarchiver.feature.feature.group Sonatype, Inc.

Comment: Ricardo Can i maybe get you to try and download the sourcecode from sourceforge, and try and add it to eclipse ? (trunk part).
because it keeps messing up for me, have tried x30 times by now, updated everything, checked the android-maven-plugin stuff, etc. etc.
Just so i can be sure that it aint me? Would be a huge help if you did thanks.

Comment: This problem comes up again with Keppler when you're trying to use 3.8.2 of Maven-Android because you need an AAR libray.

Comment: @altumano - this URL no longer seems to work. It returns a 404 error when I try to access the page.

Comment: @jschabs: this is a URL to be used in Eclipse, not in browser directly. Eclipse will implicitly add some additional paths to it to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

This problem rears its ugly head again with Keppler when you're trying to use 3.8.2 of android-maven-plugin, perhaps because you need an AAR libray. The solution is documented here https://stackoverflow.com/a/7030657/176859 and leads you here: http://wiki.eclipse.org/M2E_plugin_execution_not_covered#ignore_plugin_goal.  Or you can just click on the error in the Problems window, Context-Click to get Quick Fix, and select the one to permanently disable this error; the quickfix will generate an ignore element for the consume-aar in pluginManagement, and both Eclipse and Maven will be happy.

Answer (score 1):

I am using MacOSX with Eclipse 4.3 (Krepler). What I originally tried was to install Maven via the terminal using Brew. It installed correctly Maven 3.0.4. However when I tried to import any ready maven projects (File > Import > Maven) it would display the following two errors:

> No marketplace entries found to handle Execution default-testResources

What I did is go to Help > Eclipse Marketplace and type "Maven" in the search bar and install the first default Maven client for Eclipse. Everything worked for me from this point.

Hope it helps to you too.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. Use the embedded Maven in Window / Preferences / Maven / Installations.